# reading epub file in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, epub

can you tell me a hint to start an Epub reader app for blackberry?

I want the simplest way to do it, is there any browser or UI component that can read & display it?

I want to download it from a server then view it to the user to read it.

Comment: I don't know, you asked for help...  e-Pub is based on ZIP, HTML and CSS. Starting in OS V5.0 there is a BrowserField which will render HTML. All versions of BB OS support fetching files using HTTP.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I logged into the wrong places while reading about epub files, I think I'll try to render it with `BrowserField`, but just to fix my question, I read that RMSDK can read epub and pdf, but it's not available for j2me, can it be ported?

Comment: EPUB 3 consists of a set of four specifications:

    EPUB Publications 3.0, which defines publication-level semantics and overarching conformance requirements for EPUB Publications.
    EPUB Content Documents 3.0, which defines profiles of XHTML, SVG and CSS for use in the context of EPUB Publications.
    EPUB Open Container Format (OCF) 3.0, which defines a file format and processing model for encapsulating a set of related resources into a single-file (ZIP) EPUB Container.
    EPUB Media Overlays 3.0, which defines a format and a processing model for synchronization of text and audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple of days ago, an Epub reader library was added [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/epubreader-omt/),  I tried to use it, but it has some difficulties, it could open Epubs only from resources, but not from file system, so I decided to download the source and do some adaptation.
First, I wrote a small function that opens the Epub file as a stream:

```
public static InputStream GetFileAsStream(String fName) {
    FileConnection fconn = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    try {
        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector
                .open(fName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        is = fconn.openDataInputStream();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return is;
```

Then, I replaced the call that opens the file in `com.omt.epubreader.domain.epub.java`, so it became like this:

```
public Book getBook(String url)
{
    InputStream in = ConnectionController.GetFileAsStream(url);

    ...
    return book;
}
```

after that, I could read the file successfully, but a problem appeared, it wasn't able to read the sections, i.e. the `.html` files, so I went into a short debug session before I found the problem, whoever wrote that library, left the code that read the .html file names empty, in `com.omt.epubreader.parser.NcxParser` it was like this:

```
private void getBookNcxInfo()
{
    ...

    if(pars.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && 
                    pars.getName().toLowerCase().equals(TAG_CONTENT))
    {
        if(pars.getAttributeCount()>0)
        {

        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I just added this line to the `if` clause:

```
contentDataFileName.addElement(pars.getAttributeValue("", "src"));
```

and after that, it worked just perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for finding bug : Please Find [latest version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/epubreader-omt/files/) for api